# Anyone know why this file is recording on local host but not on github server?

Tags: javascript, speech-recognition

The red record button is supposed to show in the tab and  `console.log` you are recording

No Output I am getting but it works on my local server. Please help me
Thank you the github site is https://codingoni.github.io/VoiceBot/. There is only one button on the page. `const btn =  document.querySelector('.talk');`  `const content = document.querySelector('.content');`

```
// Responses

const greetings = ['Hi there!','Whats Going on?','I am good how are you' ];


//Weather Integration http://weatherjs.com/

//Must Change Lectures to get correct keywords
let google = 'https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=INSERT_YOUR_API_KEY&cx=017576662512468239146:omuauf_lfve&q=lectures'
//

const SpeechRecognition =  window.SpeechRecognition || window.webkitSpeechRecognition;
const recognition = new SpeechRecognition();

recognition.onstart = ()=> {
    console.log ('voice is activated, you can talk to me');
};

recognition.onresult = (event)=> {
    const current = event.resultIndex;
    const transcript = event.results[current[0]].transcript;
    content.textContent = transcript;
    readOutLoud(transcript);
};

// add the listener to the button

btn.addEventListener('click',()=>{
    recognition.start();
});

function readOutLoud(message){
    const speech= new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
    speach.text = 'I am not sure what that means'

    if (message.includes('Hi'||'Hey'||'How`s it going'||'What`s Happening')) {
       const finatlText = grettings[Math.floor(Math.random()*greetings.length)];
        speech.finalText;
    }else if (message.includes('How are you')) {
        const finatlText = grettings[2]
        speech.finalText;
    } else if  (message.includes('Todays Date'))        {

        const finatlText = new Date();
        speech.finalText;
    }
     //Weather Coming Soon
    speech.volume = 1;
    speech.rate= 1;
    speech.pitch = 2;


    window.speechSynthesis.speak(speech)
}
```

Comment: app.js is not loading - 404!

Comment: I changed app to App as its file name should this help?

Comment: The file _name_ should match what is in the file system (currently `app.js`).  So change that back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the name of you javascript file is `app.js`, you need to change the `src` attribute of your `<script>` tag to include your repository name. Like this:

`<script src="/VoiceBot/app.js"></script>`

That will fix you up.

Comment: The App JS File is loading but it is still not recording.

Comment: It isn't loading for me.